# transition class work only in first time angular js

Tags: css, angularjs

I try when click in button , will toggle class transition of 
Here is my code

```
function linkFc(scope,element,attr) {
            var toggle =angular.element(document.querySelector('.fa-bars'));
            toggle.on('click',function(){
                element.toggleClass('toggle');
            })
            }
```

Here is my plnkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/1403TdWErBAzrdbszkGo?p=preview
Where is my wrong ? Please help me

Comment: Dear jesus, why don't you use `<button class="fa-bars" ng-class="{toggle: btn.clicked}" ng-click="btn.clicked = !btn.clicked">Hi</button>`

Comment: That would be a simpler way to toggle the class, but the question refers to the transition not working - I'm assuming you want to transition the menu back to full width when you click the hamburger button - is that correct?

Comment: @tw_hoff yes . I want it

Comment: @AlonEitan thank for suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the width of the nav menu to transition back to 300px when you click the hamburger, you need to mover you `transition` rule to the base sate CSS block, you currently have it in the `.toggle .nav-side-menu` block, which is only applied when the parent element has the `.toggle` class.

Move the `transition: all 1s ease;` rule to the `.nav-side-menu` block to achieve the desired effect.

On another note, please read some articles about code quality and formatting. Your code is very messy, which will make it harder for others (and yourself) to read and maintain in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much . I just newbie in angular . Can you introduce for me some articles ?

Comment: Google is your friend. I can point you in the right direction for learning good practises about CSS.

First, I would recommend reading about CSS specificity and selector types - inline styles, IDs and classes. Next I would recommend reading something like [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/book/) (scalable and modular architecture for CSS). It might seem confusing at first, but even just knowing about this (without understanding it immediately) will save you many headaches moving forward. Good luck!